# MySql error 1215

Tags: mysql

I want to "import" the values from column x (table a) in column a_x (table b).

Why do I get this error: **Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint**

```
 CREATE TABLE a(
 id int primary key,
 x int);

 CREATE TABLE b(

 id int primary key,
 a_x int,
 foreign key (a_x) references a(x));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an index on a(x). Don't worry guys I will delete the answer :)

```
CREATE TABLE a(
 id int primary key,
 x int,
 key(x)
 );

 CREATE TABLE b(

 id int primary key,
 a_x int,
 foreign key (a_x) references a(x));
```

### Edit (for left-most)

As far as composite keys (which are combos of more than 1 column), you will note that the following works fine too, as `x` is left-most in composite

```
CREATE TABLE a
(   id int primary key,
    x int,
    y int,
    key(x,y)
);

CREATE TABLE b
(   id int primary key,
    a_x int,
    foreign key (a_x) references a(x)
);
```

### But that the following would not work

```
CREATE TABLE a
(   id int primary key,
    x int,
    y int,
    key(y,x)
);

CREATE TABLE b
(   id int primary key,
    a_x int,
    foreign key (a_x) references a(x)
);
```

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Because `x` is **not** a left-most key in *referenced* table, and therefore quick lookup would hinder system performance.

Mysql [Using foreign key constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Does that "key" index make x a primary key ?

Comment: no sir, it just needs to be a left most key (either solo or in a composite left-most), and not even unique

Comment: I am just trying to find an adequate dupe question to avoid blowback